# Splitting a word into 2 in all possible ways in python

Tags: python

How do I split a word into 2 in all possible ways in python?

Input - Eg: Stack

Output - {S, tack},{St,ack},{Sta, ck}, {Stac,k}

I thought of writing a for loop but is there a better way?
I can't think of a method by using itertools package. It changes the order of letters in the word.

Comment: If you had to do this yourself, where would you start? Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service.

Comment: Edited question. Please check

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far (forming a [mcve]), example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [tour] and [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can slice the word by index to get the combination you want

```
word = 'Stack'    
[ [word[:i],word[i:]] for i in range(1,len(word))]

[['S', 'tack'], ['St', 'ack'], ['Sta', 'ck'], ['Stac', 'k']]
```

Comment: As stated in [answer], please avoid answering unclear, overly-broad, typo, opinion-based, unreproducible, or duplicate questions. Write-my-code requests and low-effort homework questions are off-topic for [so] and more suited to professional coding/tutoring services. Good questions adhere to [ask], include a [mcve], have research effort, and have the potential to be useful to future visitors. Answering inappropriate questions harms the site by making it more difficult to navigate and encouraging further such questions, which can drive away other users who volunteer their time and expertise.

Comment: I guess writing for loop was the best way but you wrote it as a list comprehension.

Comment: I was actually looking for a solution using itertools package but it changes the order of letter too.